# Extracting word count From an XML File

Tags: java, dom, jaxb, sax

(This question is related to the previous question I posted earlier on stackoverflow...here is the link

[Extracting Values From an XML File Either using XPath, SAX or DOM for this Specific Scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107624/extracting-values-from-an-xml-file-either-using-xpath-sax-or-dom-for-this-speci))

The question is that keeping the above case in mind, instead of getting sentences, if i would like to get the words written by each participant in all sentences. For Example. if the word 'Budget' is used ten times in total and seven times by participant 'Dolske' and three times by others. So I need the list of all words and how many times it is written by each participant? Also the list of words in each turn?

What is the best strategy to achieve this? Any sample codes?

The XML is attached here (you can also check it in the referred question)

"(495584) Firefox - search suggestions passes wrong previous result to form history"

```
<Turn>
  <Date>'2009-06-14 18:55:25'</Date>
  <From>'Justin Dolske'</From>
  <Text>
    <Sentence ID = "3.1"> Created an attachment (id=383211) [details] Patch v.2</Sentence>
    <Sentence ID = "3.2"> Ah. So, there's a ._formHistoryResult in the....</Sentence>
    <Sentence ID = "3.3"> The simple fix it to just discard the service's form history result.</Sentence>
    <Sentence ID = "3.4"> Otherwise it's trying to use a old form history result that no longer applies for the search string.</Sentence>
  </Text>
</Turn>

<Turn>
  <Date>'2009-06-19 12:07:34'</Date>
  <From>'Gavin Sharp'</From>
  <Text>
    <Sentence ID = "4.1"> (From update of attachment 383211 [details])</Sentence>
    <Sentence ID = "4.2"> Perhaps we should rename one of them to _fhResult just to reduce confusion?</Sentence>
  </Text>
</Turn>

<Turn>
  <Date>'2009-06-19 13:17:56'</Date>
  <From>'Justin Dolske'</From>
  <Text>
    <Sentence ID = "5.1"> (In reply to comment #3)</Sentence>
    <Sentence ID = "5.2"> &amp;gt; (From update of attachment 383211 [details] [details])</Sentence> 
    <Sentence ID = "5.3"> &amp;gt; Perhaps we should rename one of them to _fhResult just to reduce confusion?</Sentence>
    <Sentence ID = "5.4"> Good point.</Sentence>
    <Sentence ID = "5.5"> I renamed the one in the wrapper to _formHistResult. </Sentence>
    <Sentence ID = "5.6"> fhResult seemed maybe a bit too short.</Sentence>
  </Text>
</Turn>
```

.....
  and so on

Help will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Get all of the values, better use sTax parser, it is good for such kind of tasks. Then split all of the senteces in words and do whatever you want.
Like create a model with Class Turn, where you store the author and the sentences, write services for this class and go on. :)

To split sentence in words, use split() or StringTokenizer, but tokenizer is deprecated. To use split, create a temp array, like

```
stringArray = sentence.toString().split(" ");
```

or like "sentence.getValue()", whatever.

where in method parameter you put the regEx. In your case it is a simple space, cause it splits the sentence. Then you could just go over the words and count what you need.

In case of ArrayList, use List.toArray() to get your list in the array view.

Comment: I already have a list of sentences by each participant ArrayList<String> sentenceList. Is there any way to get all words from each sentences? is this a hard approach? I am just avoiding to write the code again...

Comment: My friend, there is a bunch of methods to split senteces in words. I will edit my answer.